# Conditional formatting not showing in Excel Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, excel, excel-web-access-webpart

I have applied conditional formatting to a Pivot Table. In the Excel desktop application, everything works fine. However, the conditional formatting does not appear in Excel Web Parts or Web Page Viewer. If I download the Excel document from either part and open the document in the desktop application, the formatting appears again. I have tried loading the SharePoint page in Chrome and IE.

Is it not possible to view conditional formatting on SharePoint? If so, are there any workarounds to highlight rows if a date is a certain value so that the formatting appears in SharePoint?

Comment: Conditional Formatting should work. However, there are some limitations (fonts, some border lines, certain calculations, etc.) that may be causing an issue for you. Here's a list of the differences between viewing Excel online vs the Desktop client: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6?CorrelationId=5b5f6fbe-705b-47f0-85fc-03e852582b0d&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1&ocmsassetID=HA010369179

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain it, but it seems I was experiencing a bug. I changed one of the rules to make the grid lines red instead of making the fill red, and all of the sudden all of my rules starting working on SharePoint.